# ReactJS - ES6 class - call super() with augmented properties

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is what I would like to do:

```
constructor(props, store) {
  props.store = store;
  super(props);
};
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Can't add property store, object is not extensible

I understand that properties are immutable in ReactJS. So how can I clone, then augment the existing properties?

**UPDATE 1**

Some background: I'm basically trying to avoid a `this._store` "private" variable, and would rather have it in the `props`, since the value is known at object creation time and will not change.

My class hierarchy is as follows:

```
import SpeakersStore from ...;
class SpeakersViewController extends ItemsViewController {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props, SpeakersStore);
  };
  ...
};

class ItemsViewController extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, store) {
    props.store = store;
    super(props);
  };
  ...
};
```

Comment: What is the scenario here? I don't think that you can do such a thing in React. But I can imagine that there is a way around the problem.

Comment: Why not pass the store as another prop from the parent component or React.createElement call?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the following:

```
constructor(props, store) {
  super({...props, store});
}
```

If you're in an environment where the object spread operator (the `{...props}` construct) is not available, then you can use `Object.assign`:

```
constructor(props, store) {
  super(Object.assign({}, props, {store});
}
```

However, if this is a constructor for a React component, be aware that the second argument to the constructor for `React.Component` is `context`, and you won't get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Better to use `Object.assign` since this question mentioned nothing about ES7 or  Babel.

Comment: I'm using Babel so no worries about spreads... Your code makes sense and looks like it should work, but I still end up with the same props, i.e. without my extra store.

Comment: Gonna need more info then. How is your class being constructed? Is it a React component? (If so, see my last paragraph above). How is the store being constructed?